# Angular BehaviorSubject is not working on first load

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have defined a `BehaviorSubject` in `profile.service.ts` file which holds `false` as initial value and I am subscribing it from `profileDialog.component.ts` component in `ngOnInit` function and updating the value from `false` to `true` in `home.component.ts` this component.

When I log in to the site and the page loads, then the subscriber present in `profileDialog.component.ts` component is not subscribing when the value is getting changed from `false` to `true`.

But when I reload the page, then all works as expected.

**profile.service.ts:**

```js
export class ProfileService {
  private displayProfileDialogSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public setProfileDialogBoolean(value: boolean) {
    this.displayProfileDialogSubject.next(value);
  }

  public getProfileDialog() {
    return this.displayProfileDialogSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**home.component.ts:**

```js
export class HomeComponent {
  showProfileDialog() {
    this.profileService.setProfileDialogBoolean(true);
  }
}
```

*`showProfileDialog()` function will be called on a button in click in `home.component.html` file.*

**profileDialog.component.ts:**

```js
ngOnInit {
  this.profileDialogSubscription = this.profileService.getProfileDialog().subscribe(isOpen => {
      if (isOpen) {
        console.log("Profile dialog will be opened.");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Comment: Remove `.asObservable()` from your get method `getProfileDialog` and just subscribe directly to `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: What is a changeDetection strategy on the component?

Comment: Show more: @Component decorator and how "isOpen" is handled in the template

Comment: @smithnblack, why would you recomment that? Might make sense not to expose the subject.

Comment: `.asObservable()` is not the problem. I assume that the change detection is not trigerred for the component

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your service. if you're using providedIn: 'root' in your service with @Injectable() you don't need to include it in the providers array of any module. Since it considered as a single instance and it can be used across the application without providing it in any module.

If your Serive exists the below code

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

Then remove the service class in the providers array in your module.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the bevahiorSubject already emitted the initial value before your subscription starts (so you missed the initial value), have a look at hot observables vs cold observables